# How to measure the reflectance of a material without using a Spectralon

Tags: diffuse

I am trying to measure the reflectance% of a surface (it is made of Teflon and is very white). I am using a line spectrometer. I believe the piece can replace an expensive Spectralon for some experiments. To show that it has a quite acceptable reflectance, I need to draw its reflectance plot at different wavelengths similar to the chart presented with Spectralon. See the below image.
[image: Reflectance spectrum of Spectralon]

I had a look at different pieces of literature and I found out with two spectrum recordings of direct light source facing the spectrometer and illuminating the surface with the light then recording its reflection I am able to calculate the reflectance. To do so, I normalized the two readings with respect to the exposure times and I divided the two signals (surface spectrum divided by direct illumination spectrum) and this graph is obtained.
[image: Reflectance]

I also attached the Digital Number read by camera here.
[image: Teflon Digital Number normalized by the exposure time]
[image: Digital Number from direct light]

The detail of the experimental setup is as follows:
1- The camera angle is 45 degrees with respect to the surface and the illumination light is facing 45 degrees to the surface.

Comment: I am not really sure if this is the right place for your question since this site is about generating computer graphics and not about measurement techniques. I don't say that it doesn't fit here, I am just not sure if this community can provide you with an answer.

Comment: Keyvan, I suggest to post your question in Radiance forum. Though it's not a specific software question, the Radiance community is likely to give you the answer.

Comment: Here: https://discourse.radiance-online.org/